# Outlook slow connection and "A stable connection to the server could not be established." with MailCore2

Tags: ios, objective-c, outlook, imap, mailcore2

Im trying to fetch all mails headers from outlook, I successfully login to the account and calls like [session fetchAllFoldersOperation] and work without problems even fetching mails.

Im requesting all the headers in batches of 50 at the time.
i'm receiving batch messages very slow and some of the request are lost. 
I receive "A stable connection to the server could not be established. error"
This is only happening with outlook, i have no problems with gmail or yahoo.

this is my session configuration.

```
self.username = username;
self.password = password;
self.hostname = ^ NSString *(SCMMailProvider provider) {
    if (provider == SCMServiceProviderGmail) {
        return @"imap.gmail.com";
    } else if (provider == SCMServiceProviderHotmail) {
        return @"imap-mail.outlook.com";
    } else if (provider == SCMServiceProvideriCloud) {
        return @"imap.mail.me.com";
    } else if (provider == SCMServiceProviderYahoo) {
        return @"imap.mail.yahoo.com";
    }

    return nil;
}(provider);

if (provider == SCMServiceProvideriCloud || provider == SCMServiceProviderOther) {
    self.mailsFolder = kSCMMailFolderInbox;
    [self setAuthType:MCOAuthTypeSASLNone];
} else {
    [self setOAuth2Token:password];
    [self setUsername:username];
    if (provider == SCMServiceProviderHotmail) {
        [self setAuthType:MCOAuthTypeXOAuth2Outlook];
        self.mailsFolder = kSCMMailFolderInbox;
    } else if (provider == SCMServiceProviderGmail) {
        [self setAuthType:MCOAuthTypeXOAuth2];
        self.mailsFolder = kSCMGmailAllMessagesFolder;
    }
}

MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation *fetchOp = [self fetchMessagesByNumberOperationWithFolder:self.mailsFolder
                                                                            requestKind:MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindStructure | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders
                                                                                numbers:uidSet];
[fetchOp start:^(NSError *messageFetchingError, NSArray *msgs, MCOIndexSet *vanished) {
}
```

Comment: What happens when you set a longer timeout value?

Comment: The same thing slow download and “A stable connection to the server could not be established.” I've tried with oAuth2 and regular credentials with no luck.

Comment: What does the connection logger show?

Comment: I've just made a test with the logger it doesn't show more than the headers logs. I'm fetching 50 headers by batch and it's taking 8 seconds each one. is very slow or is the normal? gmail fetch a lot way faster than that.

Comment: Is it taking more than 30 seconds at some point? I don't get why the timeout happens. And sure, 8 seconds is very slow.

Comment: After a few test i discover that there's a few mails that have 15 attachments takes longer to come back so that is when the timeout happens . I'm requesting only headers and kind structure i did test with only headers and with only structure and happens the same. Increasing the timeout helps but what about the download rate is 1kb or 2kb :s it takes forever to download just the headers

Comment: I set timout to 100 and is not helping 2015-01-20 13:52:18.747 OutlookMail[3021:105822] A stable connection to the server could not be established.

Comment: Have you tried MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindFullHeaders?

Comment: No luck with that one, gmail give almost 1 mb/s, outlook 8 kb when i'm lucky

Comment: It sounds like Outlook IMAP server is slow: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-ofolders/why-has-imap-speed-on-outlookcom-slowed-down/06978cf8-9423-4115-8579-6dead78aa092 and it doesn't even work properly with Thunderbird.

Comment: the weird thing is that some mail apps like mailbox fetch email via imap fast

Comment: mailbox doesn't do IMAP. They http to their servers.

Comment: so i think i should do that then. thank you very much for your help!

Comment: though mailbox isn't compatible with Outlook.